# date.split() is not a function

Tags: javascript, date, vue.js, split

I have a string which contains a date in the format 'DD-MM-YYYY'. I want to format it to 'DD/MM/YYY'. Hence I am using split method for it.

It splits the string and formats the date in the correct way. So all good.

What bugs me is it throws an error that .split() is not a function

I have tried changing the method to multiline, just for the purpose of debugging, it didn't work.
I also tried to output the data type of my string to confirm what I am splitting is actually a string. Variable is a string and still throws the same error.

```
formatDate(date) {
  if (!date) return null
  const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`
}
```

date argument that is being passed to formatDate is a string ('29-09-2018')

Expected:

The 'date' should be formatted without any errors in console.

Actual:

The 'date' is getting formatted but with following error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: date.split is not a 
function
```

Comment: `date` is probably of type `Date` and not a string

Comment: what is the type of the date parameter?

Comment: *"date argument that is being passed to formatDate is a string ('29-09-2018')"* Clearly not; if it were, it would have `split`. So what you need to do is debug it: Set a breakpoint on that line and find out what `date` really is when there's a problem. Maybe make it a conditional breakpoint on `typeof date !== "string"` so the debugger only stops when it isn't a string. (Using a debugger is not something only advanced programmers should do. It's basically the first thing you should learn to do after "Hello, World".)

Comment: You code does not work because you have not put the word function in front of formatDate.

Comment: @1556089774 I know, but providing a non-working code sample is unhelpful.

Comment: @MattEllen you don't need that keyword if it's part of the Vue component's `methods` block. E.g. https://codesandbox.io/embed/p9ropyrp60 - in fact the code will break _with_ the `function` keyword in this scenario.

Comment: @jameswhiteley you learn something new every day

Comment: A case of not providing a working example makes it difficult to answer.  Example, how is this called etc.

Comment: I just guessed it was a component method since the question is tagged Vue. Could be completely wrong tbf.

Comment: If it is a string it would be simpler to use *replace*: `d.replace(/-/g, '/')`.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way.

If you read my question carefully, I asserted that the string is getting split and that the date in it is getting formatted. It's just the vue, that is throwing an error.

As absurd the authenticity of the question sounds (given that my question has been down voted), it is still an issue.

What I did is:

```
computed: {
  dateFormatted() {
    this.formatDate(this.startDate.toString())
  }
 }
```

The weird part is ,'this.startDate' is string and when it is passed to 'formatDate()', it is still fetched as string. So I am guessing, in the interim, is when this issue occurs.

Comment: formatDate function is based on "split" a method which is available only on strings. As you can see, it's split by a "-" sign, and an array of strings is returned. Basically you cannot pass a dare to formatDate. You must convert the date into a string, or update the function to receive a Date object.